# TB database backup and move

Tags: sql-server, backup

For a SQL Server 2019 we want to backup a 3 TB database to another DB and we want very minimum downtime what is the best way?

Thanks

Comment: Simply configure logshipping. If you want bit more complex go for BAG or AG depending on edition of SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 1):

You can minimise downtime by restoring a FULL backup with NORECOVERY and then restoring log backups with NORECOVERY. These log restores can be automated to continue until you're ready for cutover.

At the point of cutover, you perform a [Tail-Log Backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/tail-log-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) of the database on the current server, then restore this tail log backup on the new server with RECOVERY. The tail-log backup takes the DB offline on the old server and restoring with RECOVERY brings it online on the new server without losing any committed transactions.

Once restored, you redirect your applications to the new server. The downtime is the combined total of the time required to backup the tail log, restore the tail log and redirect your applications to the new server. This is usually significantly less than a FULL restore, especially for a multi-TB database.

How you automate the log restores will depend on your current backup configuration. If you have a backup tool like CommVault, there are likely features built-in to replicate the data to a second server. If you're using native backups, you could use something like log shipping to automate the process, or you could write a PowerShell script (using something like [dbatools](https://dbatools.io)) to automate the restores.

You could also follow a similar approach using a [clusterless Availability Group](https://sqlha.com/alwayson-availability-groups-no-underlying-cluster-sql-server-v-next/) and simply 'failover' to the new server when you're ready to cutover.

Comment: I generally also recommend setting the original database to READ_ONLY prior to the tail-log backup; some of the worst problems you can have area mix of writes going to the old and the new, as when a repointing change takes time to propagate.